# Trigger add tuples in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm studying the triggers recently and I can not immediately understand this:

QUERY: insert the screening of the film only if the year of production of the film is smaller than the year inserted in the projection.

```
USE cin_film; // database

drop trigger if exists vincoloPro;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER vincoloPro
before INSERT ON projection
for each row
begin
DECLARE C INTEGER;
SET @c = (SELECT year from film where id_film = new.id_film);
// insert in c the year corresponding to the film inserted in the tuple
IF (CAST (YEAR (NEW.giorno) AS UNSIGNED) <c) THEN
// convert to integer the year entered on projection day
     SIGNAL sqlstate '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You have missed the year';
ELSE
     SIGNAL sqlstate '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ADDIOS!';
END IF;
END;

$$

DELIMITER;
```

But despite the year of production of the film is greater than the year of screening the film, it makes me enter the new tuple quietly:
for example:
MOVIE:

```
+ --------- + ------------ + -------------------------- -------- + ------------ + ------ +
| id_film | id_regista | title | gender | year |
+ --------- + ------------ + -------------------------- -------- + ------------ + ------ +
| 1 | 15 | Crash | Drama | 1996 |
| 2 | 15 | False Sembianze | Comedy | 1988 |
| 3 | 14 | Pulp Fiction | Police | 1994 |
| 4 | 13 | Breaking the waves | Drama | 1996 |
| 5 | 13 | Dogville | Drama | 2002 |
| 6 | 12 | Alamo | Western | 1960 |
| 7 | 18 | Dangerously in three | Spying | 1985 |
| 8 | 19 | White horse, black heart | Drama | 1989 |
| 9 | 19 | In the garden of good and evil | Police | NULL |
| 10 | 21 | American Beauty | Drama | 1999 |
| 11 | NULL | The exchange | NULL | 2008 |
+ --------- + ------------ + -------------------------- -------- + ------------ + ------ +

mysql> INSERT INTO projection (id_cinema, id_film, day)
-> VALUES ('1', '1', '1877-04-03');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
```

(Despite id_film 1 -> Crash is from 1996> 1877)

Answer (score 0):

- You mixed up different types of variables: c & @c;
- You used `giorno` column that not in the projection table
- I'd recommend to use 'into var' syntax;
- You should use not warning class signal (**01**xyz), but exception class
  (**03**xyz).

So, here you are:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `vincoloPro` BEFORE INSERT ON `projection` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT `year` INTO @c FROM film WHERE id_film = NEW.id_film;

IF (YEAR(NEW.`day`) < @c) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '03000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You have missed the year';
ELSE
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ADDIOS!';
END IF;

END
```